# How to load texture in vertical?

Tags: android, libgdx

I'm loading texture for game background, and use SpriteBatch to draw: SriteBatch.draw(texture). But it loaded on mobile in horizontal, so how load it in vertical?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean exactly, but if you want to rotate an image you could create a sprite and give that a rotation. Otherwise you could just rotate your image using paint or the like (don't rotate it using windows image preview tool because that wont change the imagedata).

Comment: please post more code and describe better the problem